# I am searching for a spell checker which is easily implemented to work with django and python 2.7

Tags: javascript, python, django, spell-checking

I want to check for a spelling mistakes while user is typing and it should support different languages. Thanks for your help guys

Answer (score 2):

There's a nice tutorial [here](https://github.com/mattalcock/blog/blob/master/2012/12/5/python-spell-checker.rst).

Also there are several frameworks/command-line programs you could use:

- For python: [pyenchant](https://pythonhosted.org/pyenchant/).
- For JS: there are many as APIs, search for them. If you have a hunspell dict you can try [Typo](https://github.com/cfinke/Typo.js/).

Generally speaking though you should do a little background search before asking on SO.